# How to handle POST request using ZUUL for multiple services

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, routes, netflix-zuul

I have two services in two different projects.

1) Website UI

service name - website

port - 8000

2) Prediction

service name - prediction

port - 8082

I also have ZUUL running on **8008** and my service discovery on port **8761**.

The website project has all the webpages I need - home.html and dashboard.html.

Below are my ZUUL routings: application.yml

```
zuul:
  routes:
    website:
      path: /
      serviceId: website
      stripPrefix: false

    form1:
      path: /form1
      serviceId: prediction
      stripPrefix: false

    dashboard:
      path: /dashboard
      serviceId: website
      stripPrefix: false
```

In the home.html of Website project, I have a form with POST action that should call a POST method in the Prediction project.
So what should my for action be?
something like this -

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:8008/form1">
```

My ZUUL is on 8008. 
Is this the right way?

And in the "/form" post method of Prediction service, I need to do some actions and then navigate to another another webpage "dashboard.html" of the website project. While using the above mentioned the form action, I am not able to redirect to any other page.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Move your website out of zuul.

In your web pages, use ajax to visit zuul to get data from web services.

PS: If you want do add LB to your website, you'd better use nginx.

[image: zuul]

Comment: Even if I separate my Website from Zuul, I still need to make POST calls to the WebAPIs. So for those calls, I'll have to use Zuul routings, no?
Or, is there a way to make the POST  method for a form using Ajax?
I'm new to this. So not sure if we can do that.

Comment: Regardless of using Ajax calls, your calls to the backend will always go through Zuul.